# Cython magic command doesn't print in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, cython, conda

I am trying to use cython in Anaconda - jupyter notebook.
I wrote the following code:

```
%load_ext Cython

%%cython
print("Hello")
```

And it's seems to interpetered without errors, but there is no output to the console.

tnx

Comment: I guess first time you run it, it has printed "Hello"...

Comment: It doesn't print also in the first time

Comment: @IdoIkar Have you tried using a new notebook? Can you share the contents of the Conda environment?